# jquery autocomplete does not print the results

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to use for the first time the `autocomplete` feature of jquery ui, but I can't get it to work properly

javascript code:

```
$("#search_input").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON( "do.php", { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id, get: request }, function(result){
      /*response($.map(result, function(item) {
        return item.NAME;
      }));*/
      response(result);
      console.log(result);
    })
  },
  minLength: 2
});
```

It returns data, but it won't show up: http://i46.tinypic.com/1z85c0.png

I've even tried adding some css to see if it works:

```
.ui-autocomplete{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reading this article: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/

So this is how I use it and it works:

```
$("#search_input").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, add) {
        $.getJSON("do.php", { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id, get: request }, function(results){

          consoloe.log(results)
          var suggestions = [];

          $.each(results, function(i, val){
            suggestions.push(val.headline)
          });

          add(suggestions);

        });
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON should return `label` and `value` parameters, not `id` and `headline`.

> An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
>   [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: but how? hardcoded? the data in `result` is returned by a `print_r(json_encode($data['search_results']));` which is build with the result from a mysql query

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, but I would assume you need to alias the fields in the query if the field names are being read directly. It's probably best to ask a new question if you have problems with that though.

Comment: so if I was to have something like: `[ { label: "123155", value: "Welcom to Stackoverflow" }, ... ]` is correct?

Comment: Yes, that should work, although you probably want label = Welcome, value = 123155.

Comment: `Object { value="1545520", label="Movistar"}` still no success, and now... it doesn't show up anything... not even that small thing in the picture where the arrow is